# Angular Material Datepicker - Incorrect date passed

Tags: angular, datepicker, angular-material, datetime-format, utc

I am pulling my hair out with this, and I know it has been answered a million times before.  But I cannot seem to find a solution to the problem.

I am using Angular material datepicker with a custom date provider to format the date.

This is what it looks like:

```
import { NativeDateAdapter } from ‘@angular/material’;
import { MatDateFormats } from ‘@angular/material/core’;
export class AppDateAdapter extends NativeDateAdapter {
  format(date: Date, displayFormat: Object): string {
    if (displayFormat === ‘input’) {
      let day: string = date.getDate().toString();
      day = +day < 10 ? ‘0’ + day : day;
      let month: string = (date.getMonth() + 1).toString();
      month = +month < 10 ? ‘0’ + month : month;
      let year = date.getFullYear();
      return `${day}-${month}-${year}`;
    }
    return date.toDateString();
  }
}
export const APP_DATE_FORMATS: MatDateFormats = {
  parse: {
    dateInput: { month: ‘short’, year: ‘numeric’, day: ‘numeric’ },
  },
  display: {
    dateInput: ‘input’,
    monthYearLabel: { year: ‘numeric’, month: ‘numeric’ },
    dateA11yLabel: { year: ‘numeric’, month: ‘long’, day: ‘numeric’
    },
    monthYearA11yLabel: { year: ‘numeric’, month: ‘long’ },
  }
};
```

Now, the issue is, when I pass `02 Jan 2019`, the date is displayed fine. But when submitting the data and inspecting the payload, the date is passed as `2019-02-01T22:00:00.000Z`.  Now I know this has to do with UTC, but I cannot seem to fix the issue.  When using no provider at all, or extending `MomentDateAdapter`, the date is passed fine as `2019-02-01T00:00:00.000Z`

My real issue is that when I create another provider and extend `MomentDateAdapter` instead of `NativeDateAdapter`, everything is perfect.  BUT, I cannot format the date for the `MomentDateAdapter`.

I have even tried returning the date formatted as `moment().utc()` but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue, but I use MomentDateAdapter and when I receive the date in my component I use moment to format instead of formating in the adapter and it seems to work.
That problems seems to me that is caused by the timezone and using moment().utc() will not give you your current timezone